# Adding events via places return 404 error:

Tags: php, google-places-api

Please excuse my terminology if I get anything wrong, I'm new to Google API

I'm trying to add events via the Places API, for a single venue (listed under the bar category). I've followed the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=places-events-screencast#event_intro

and this is the URL I am posting to (via PHP)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/format?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAFd-ivmfNRDanJ40pWsgP1 (key altered)

which returns a 404 error. If I have understood correctly, I have set the sensor to false as I am not mobile, and created an API key in Google apis, with the PLACES service turned on.

Have I missed a vital step here, or would a subsequent error in the POST submission cause a 404 error? I can paste my code in but I thought I'd start with the basics.

Many thanks for your help, advice and time. It's very much apprecciated.

I've added this line to my CurlCall function which I believe should specify a POST, and the result is still the same.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

so the whole functions reads

```
function CurlCall($url,$topost)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $topost);
            $body = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $body;
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'URL ' . $url;
            echo '<br>';
            return $body;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the POST method and not GET?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the code which i'm using, I can't find any reference to POST or GET in the posts I've been utilising, and the php docs aren't helping me too much there either>

Comment: function CurlCall($url,$topost)
   {
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $topost);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $body;
       echo 'URL ' . $url;
    return $body;

   }

Comment: Google for "curl POST". You're almost there!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I've updated my function (see the main question) with this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 but it still doesn't work. Am I still doing something wrong? Thanks again

Comment: i think my url was causing the error. i hadn't changed "format" to "json" (or "xml"). i am onto a new error now but little steps etc. thanks again @dotancohen

Comment: Good luck with it. Don't forget that the Google APIs implement valid REST services so you must always use the correct Method (POST or GET). As Curl (and other third-party libraries) defaults to GET this is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format of your request in the URL by changing the word format to either `json` or `xml` depending on how you are going to structure and `POST` your request.

XML:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/xml?sensor=false&key=your_api_key

JSON:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key=your_api_key